# Can we say "I like there" or "I like here" in American English?

Tags: word-usage

Let's say someone told me that he was from a particular country, can I say **"I like there."** to that person to mean **"I like that place."**? Also, can I say **"I like here."** to mean that I like the place I'm at?

I'm wondering if we can say these in American English because there is a difference between BE and AE in terms of the usage of "there" in those kind of sentences as far as I know. For example, from what I heard, British people don't say sentences like "I visited there." while Americans can say it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circumstances under which you can say *I like here* and *I like there* are very narrow, when **here** and **there** are your choices and you are turning the words into *ad hoc* labels for the two locations:

> For this part of the show, you can stand here or there.
>   -- I like here.

If we are referring to the ambience of a place, we say *I like **it** here* or *I like **it** there* as Lambie says in his answer.

The reason for this is that these words are *deictic*, referring to more than a mere location: they refer to the location *from a certain perspective*, usually the speaker's, and so owing to that complexity they do not serve as complements of **like**.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to mix apples and oranges.

Comment: Thanks. So, to exactly mean that I like a place, I have to say sentences like "I like that place/this place.", "I like that country/this country.", "I like that park/this park" etc. I cannot say "I like there/here". It's both grammatically and idiomatically wrong based on what you said. Okay. Btw, I think "I like it there" would be weird if I have never been to the place I'm referring to. For example Australia seems like a nice country to me, but I wouldn't say "I like it there" referring to Australia since I've never been there. But you are saying "I like there" is also wrong.

Comment: So if I'm talking about Australia, I can say **"I like that place"** or **"I like that country"**, but I cannot say **"I like there"**. This is what I understood from the answers I received here.

Comment: @Fire and Ice: You are correct: **it** in "I like it there" refers to something *in your experience* and so to say those words of a place implies that you've been there, and if you haven't been there, it would be an odd thing to say.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an AmE or BrE issue at all.

In English, we say:

**I like it here.** or **I like it there.** to mean: I like being or living in some place.

If you are in the place (city, town, area, region, country, etc.), you say: I like it here. If you are not, you say: I like it there.

This is basically idiomatic. **The it stands for**: living or being in a place.

Also, yes, in English, we say: I visited a place [city, town, region, country) and also say,for example, for that (tourism): I went to [some place] last year.

There is nothing wrong with saying "visit a place" (visit here or there) in English and again, there is no difference between AmE and BrE.

[the verb like has to be followed by an object (verb or object) unless it is being used with the function word **to**.]

I like **being/living here**. = I like it here. 
I like **being/living there**.= I like it there.

**It** replaces the **implied being or living**.

I like playing piano. I like **it**. **Playing piano.** If I say: "I like it here" that means: I like playing piano here. [in this place].

**Visit cannot be followed by anything but a place or a noun that stands for it**: I visit here [noun] every year. I visit there [noun] every year. I visit it [the city, noun]  every year.

**like can be followed by a verb** = I like **living or being here**. **being or living here or there** can be replaced by just **it** but you must keep here or there, otherwise the meaning changes.

Comment: Thank you. There is probably a difference between the American usage and the British usage though. Look at this one please: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/visit-there-versus-visit-it.2720376/ Also I didn't say the usages of "visit a place" are different. I said the usages of "visit there" were different.

Comment: Please edit your answer. I didn't say anything about "visit a place". I said "visit there".

Comment: @FireandIce  Your link is just one random comment on some forum without any supporting evidence.  I can't imagine why it's uncommon in all the many dialects of BrE to say "I visited there" as it's a perfectly ordinary sentence.  It's possible they prefer a different verb like "traveled", or "went to", but that has nothing to do with "there".

Comment: @Andrew Why can't we say **"I like there/here"** instead of **"I like that place/this place"** while we can say **"I visit there/here"** instead of **"I visit that place/this place"**? This is what I can't understand.

Comment: visit here/there or a place is the same thing. One hit from wordreference.com is not really much to go on. That person is misguided.

Comment: @FireandIce Also note that there is a huge difference between "less common" and "not used at all." I am very certain that "I visited there" *is* used by people in the UK, whatever its percentage of colloquial usage may or may not be.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So do you guys all think or know that **"I like there"** and **"I like here"** are grammatically wrong when you want to mean **"I like that place/this place"**?

Comment: @Fireandice I asked a question on Meta about why people repeat their questions here when the question has already answered. About your latest question right before this post: I have already answered it. Why are you asking it again? Was it not clear that I like there/here is not right for I like that place/this place?